# rosbag will not create bag file

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

I am running rosbag from a launch file, and the terminal says the process starts cleanly.  After ending the process however, I cannot find the bag file and all my data is lost.  Here is the launch file:

```
<launch>
    <include file="$(find AK_Loc)/launch/ak_localize.launch" />
    
    <node name="Command_Predictor" pkg="cmd_predictor" type="TL_Predictor.py" />

    <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="cmds" args="-o act_and_pred_cmds /actCmds /cmdPreds" />

</launch>
```

and I am running ROS Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/68350/rosbag-will-not-create-bag-file/) by [Robocop87](https://answers.ros.org/users/5183/robocop87/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `find ~/.ros -name \*.bag`.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3